# React Native: reanimated 2 animation not shown

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native reanimated 2 to animate some action buttons from my tinder-like test app, it goes like this, each time user profile screen is focused I do a fetch with axios and depending on the data I get from my backend I want to show or hide (with a cool slide up or down animation) the action buttons.

Currently I see no animation at all, I tried console logging everything the animation seems to be being fired.

```
import { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withTiming, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const [ loadedChats, setLoadedChats ] = useState(false);

    const [ showLikeActions, setShowLikeActions ] = useState(false);
    

    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    
    const bottomPositionLikeActions = useSharedValue(-100);

   

    const createLikeActionsStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        console.log("Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to:", bottomPositionLikeActions.value);
        return {
          bottom: bottomPositionLikeActions.value,
        };
    });

   

      useEffect(() => {
        if(loadedChats)
        {
            
            if(showLikeActions)
            {
                console.log('showLikeActions',showLikeActions);
        bottomPositionLikeActions.value = withSpring(showLikeActions ? 0 : -100, {
          damping: 15,
          stiffness: 150,
          mass: 1,
        });
            }
        }
        
      }, [loadedChats]); 
   

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isFocused)
        {
            getHasMatchOrChat(root.userStore.detailUser.id);
        }
    }, [isFocused]);


    const getHasMatchOrChat = async (id) => 
    {
        
        setLoadedChats(false);
        try 
        {
             
        let payload =  {user_id:id, auth_user_id:root.userStore.user.id};
        console.log('payload',payload);
        let response = await http.get(env.BASE_URL+'/api/matches/get-has-match-or-chat-by-id', {params:payload});


        let userHasMatchWithMe = response.data.userHasMatchWithMe;
        let userHasChatWithMe = response.data.userHasChatWithMe;
        let sentLikeAction = response.data.sentLikeAction;

        if(!userHasMatchWithMe && !userHasChatWithMe && sentLikeAction == 0)
        {
            setShowLikeActions(true);
        }

        setLoadedChats(true);
           
        
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                console.log(error);
                //setLoadedChats(false);
                throw error;
            }

    };
```

And my action button (the one that's supposed to animate):

```
 <Animated.View style={[{  width: 90, height: 90,  position: 'absolute', right: 15,  borderRadius: 90 / 2,  overflow: 'hidden',  backgroundColor: '#71DFCA',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',  elevation: 10 }, createLikeActionsStyle ]}>
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={ ()=>{ onLiked() } } style={{ width:'100%',height:'100%',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center' }}>
          <OctiIcon name="heart-fill" style={{ color:'white', fontSize:50,marginTop:6 }}/>
 </TouchableOpacity>
 </Animated.View>
```

Thanks in advance